# Filter out a specific column from array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following array of objects. I wanted to make new array of object excluding `date` field.

The new array should return as follows:

```
const new_arr = [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "user": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "user": 0
       }
    ]
```

What's my mistake here?

```js
const arr = [{
    "id": 1,
    "date": 0,
    "user": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "date": 0,
    "user": 0
  }
]


const new_arr = arr.filter((items) => !items.date)

console.log(new_arr);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use map

like this

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "date": 0,
    "user": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "date": 0,
    "user": 0
   }
]

console.log(arr.map(({date, ...rest}) => ({...rest})))
```